# Array of elements becomes undefined within a class when changing with and attempting to do some adjustments

Tags: javascript

I build an object and gather all elements by class name, then on changing the with I want to do some work on them. When I construct the object it works, but within `WidthChecker()` when do some work on a width change the become `undefined`.

```
class SlickController {
    constructor () {
        this.$mobileSlicksCarousels;
    }
    Init() {
        this.$mobileSlicksCarousels = document.getElementsByClassName("slick_carousels_mobile-only"); // view in console says this is valid, I see the objects
        this.WidthChecker();
    }
    WidthChecker() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            console.log(this.$mobileSlicksCarousels); // they become undefined in here, lost and none of the content afterwords be seen
            if ($(this).width() !== width) {
                width = $(this).width();
                if (width < 491) {
                    this.$mobileSlicksCarousels.forEach( carousel => {
                        this.SlickMobile(carousel);
                    });
                } else if (width > 490) {
                    this.$mobileSlicksCarousels.forEach( carousel => {
                        this.UnSlickMobile(carousel);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    SlickMobile (toSlick) {
        console.log(toSlick);
        toSlick.slick();
    }

    UnSlickMobile (unSlick) {
        unSlick.slick('unslick');
    }
}


// call and start width checker
slick_Controller.Init();
```

I assume the issue is when I called `$(window).on('resize', function() {` because the function doesn't see the parent variables, but I'm not sure how else to approach calling a function directly on resize.

Comment: Either use an arrow function so the `this` does not change on the event handler, or store the `this` in another variable outside of the event hander, and use that variable in place of `this` in the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `this` in a variable before jumping to function or you can bind function but then you lose jquery context and cannot use `$(this)` expression.

**Take a look at the examples**

```js
class Test {
    constructor () {
        this.property = 1;
    }

    Func() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        const that = this;
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            console.log(that.property);
            console.log($(this).width());
        });
    }
    
    Func1() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        $(window).on('load', (function() {
            console.log(this.property);
            console.log($(window).width());
        }).bind(this));
    }
    
    Func2() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        $(window).on('load', this.OnResize.bind(this));
    }
    
    OnResize(event) {
      console.log(this.property);
      console.log($(event.target).width());
    }

}

const test = new Test();
test.Func();
test.Func1();
test.Func2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```